# Loadbalance nginx proxies with keepalived possible?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, keepalived

I was wondering if I could load balance 2 nginx proxies with keepalived.

I have already established high availability for 2 proxies in MASTER - BACKUP setup with keepalived. So Failover is working but not enough for me.

I want to load balance those two proxies preferably with keepalived if it is capable doing it. So (while both proxies are up) when a request is made to VIP, send the request to proxy1 or proxy2.

Is it doable by keepalived?
If it is and you know a link I would appreciate that.
If not any info would be nice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using nginx: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: I thought about it but then it defeats the purpose of loadbalacing with Keepalived. Then we are adding another layer to the system.
I thought there was a way to do it with Keepalived so that Keepalived does HA and Load balancing at same time.

Comment: any ideas anyone?

Comment: Nginx could do HA and Load balancing, so you can just use it instead of Keepalived, and do not add another layer.